# Set initial filter on a boolean field column on load

Tags: kendo-grid, filtering

[Telerik Kendo MVC Grid - How do I set onload/initial filter equals True with checkbox columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274338/telerik-kendo-mvc-grid-how-do-i-set-onload-initial-filter-equals-true-with-che)

I am trying to set a True/False column filter to True on initial load. My Viewmodel has a bool property called IsHoliday. I have followed the example in the link above but i don't have any records showing in the grid at startup. My read action returns a JSON of IEnumerable as suggested in the referenced link. My View is as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<HolidayVM>()
.Name("h_grid")  
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(15)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error")) // Handle the "error" event
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(m => m.Date);
        model.Field(m => m.Date).Editable(false);
    })
    .Filter(f => f.Add(m => m.IsHoliday.Equals(true)))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Holiday_Read", "Holiday"))
    .Update(up => up.Action("Holiday_Update", "Holiday").Data("grid_sendAntiForgery"))
)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Width(30).Format("{0:dd-MMMM}");
    columns.Bound(p => p.HolidayText).Width(100).Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.IsHoliday)
    .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsHoliday ? '' : checked='checked' # disabled='disabled' />")
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("Is equal to")))           
        .Width(30);
    columns.Command(cmd =>
    {
        cmd.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Edit" });
    }).Title("Commands").Width(25);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
)
```

Ideally I will like my grid to look like in attached image, on load, with IsHoliday set to True
[image: Grid on initial load]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

```
.Filter(f => f.Add(m => m.IsHoliday).IsEqualTo(true))
```

instead of

```
.Filter(f => f.Add(m => m.IsHoliday.Equals(true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this easily:

columns.Bound(p => p.ISProperty).ClientTemplate("#= ISProperty? 'Yes' : 'No' #")